# xml string change the header encoding using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have string of XML .
how can I change the header from:

```
string xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-8'?>";
```

to

```
string xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
```

using c#?

**UPDATE**

I tryed to get the xml to User object

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
 User user = (User)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

but in the User object I get the string not encoding well.
because of the encoding of the Xml I need to change the encoding.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the context is. Presumably you're wanting to actually re-encode all the data as well, rather than just changing the declaration? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes`.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML is stored in a string variable and you need to only replace the value in the `encoding` attribute, then you can perform a replace as following:

```cs
const string searchEncoding = "ISO-8859-8";
const string newEncoding = "UTF-8";

string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-8'?><abc></abc>";

int encodingPos = xml.IndexOf(searchEncoding);

if (encodingPos==30)
{
    xml = xml.Substring(0, encodingPos) + newEncoding + xml.Substring(encodingPos + searchEncoding.Length);
}
```

However, a different process is necessary if the XML is stored in another datatype and/or you need to re-encode the XML content.